# how to show that there is no definable function from a linearly order set into a stable set?

Tags: model-theory

Let $T$ be a complete theory. Assume that $S$ and $A$ are stably embedded sets in $U$ (the monster model). Assume that $A$ is linearly ordered and $S$ is stable. How do I show that there is no definable function $f: A \rightarrow S$ with infinite image? 
I have tried to assume the existence of such function and contradict the fact that $S$ is stable, but somehow I got stuck on the details. Is it obvious? Would it be possible to show in an explicit way which is the formula that has the order property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is not true. Maybe the intended statement was that there is no *injective* definable function from an infinite definably linearly ordered set to a stable set?

Here's a counterexample:

Let $L$ be the two-sorted language with sorts $A$ and $S$, a binary relation symbol $\leq$ on $A$, and a unary function symbol $f\colon A\to S$. Let $K$ be the class of all finite structures in this language in which $\leq$ is a linear order.  Then $K$ is a Fraïssé class. In the Fraïssé limit $M$, $A$ is a dense linear order without endpoints, $S$ is an infinite set, and $f$ is a surjective function such that for all $s\in S$, the set $f^{-1}(\{s\})$ is dense in the order. In particular, $f$ is a definable function with infinite image.

$A$ is stably embedded, because if $X$ is a definable subset of $A$, defined by $\varphi(x,a,s)$, where $a$ is a tuple of parameters from $A$ and $s$ is a tuple of parameters from $S$, we can pick a tuple $s'$ of preimages of $s$ under $f$, and letting $\psi(x,y,z)$ be $\phi(x,y,f(z))$, $X$ is also defined by $\psi(x,a,s')$, which only uses parameters from $A$.

By quantifier elimination, to check that $S$ is stably embedded, it suffices to check that every atomic formula with parameters from $M$ and variables of sort $S$ is equivalent to one with parameters from $S$. But since there are no relation symbols on $S$ and no function symbols with domain $S$, any such atomic formula which uses both a variable of sort $S$ and parameters from $A$ is just $x = f(a)$, which is clearly equivalent to a formula with parameters (just $f(a)$) from $S$.

Finally, $S$ is stable, since its induced structure is that of a pure set. By ultrahomogeneity, for any finite $B\subseteq S$, any injective function $h\colon B\to S$ extends to an automorphism of $M$, so there are no definable relations on $S$ other than those definable using equality.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @user350168 I notice you have a lot of questions with no accepted answer. If an answer resolves your question, you can accept it by clicking the green check mark on the right. In addition to acknowledging the answerer, this removes the question from the "unanswered questions" queue.

Comment: seems like you solved a lot of the questions that I had. Thanks! I just accepted them all. Sorry for the delay!